# How to configure Jenkins to do a gulp dist for every commit to a git branch?

Tags: git, github, jenkins, msbuild, gulp

I am brand new to Jenkins and am looking for some general advice. My goal with this project is simply to have Jenkins run a gulp dist for every commit to a git repo branch.

On the server which I am using Jenkins I have already downloaded gulp, bower, python, karma, ruby, sass, and npm. I've updated my workspace and made sure my tools and required plugins are up-to-date.

In Jenkins I have triggers tat builds for every commit to git.
I think the next step is to create a Windows Powershell step at the end that basically runs the following command:

```
gulp format;gulp lint;gulp test;gulp sass;gulp dist
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a [freestyle job](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_setup_build_jobs.htm) which:

- does refer your Git repo
- has a single batch step executing those commands (provided the `%PATH%` is correctly set)

For that job to be triggered, you can either:

- poll regularly the repo
- or set a post-commit hook which calls the HTTP endpoint defined by the [Jenkisn Git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin).
  Example:

  ```
  http://localhost:8080/git/notifyCommit?url=file://c:/path/to/my/repo
  ```

See more at "[Automatically triggering a Jenkins build on Git commit](http://www.andyfrench.info/2015/03/automatically-triggering-jenkins-build.html)"